# How to make view update when CoreData entity changes

Tags: swift, swiftui

## Update

Based on @Tushar Sharma's suggestion, I removed `@ObservedObject` tag from the `place` variable in both PlaceDetail.swift and EditPlaceForm.swift. This made it so that the `place` property was an argument for the view rather than a state object. I then created separate state variables in EditPlaceForm.swift to hold the values for the text inputs. I added an onAppear to the view that sets the state values using the provided `place` object. This works great, and resolves the issue of the back button disappearing. It introduced a new problem though: `PlaceDetail` doesn't update until after it's been closed and reopened. I then did some testing to see if updating the `place` variable within `PlaceDetail` itself caused an update. To do this I just added a button that changed the name of the place and saved it to the view context when pressed. The view still did not update until it was reloaded. Therefore, my question has switched to how to make the view update when `place` is updated, without using `@ObservedObject` in EditPlaceForm.swift, which caused the back button to disappear.

### Updated Pieces of Code

#### PlaceDetail.swift

Original:

```
@ObservedObject var place: Place
```

Updated:

```
var place: Place
```

#### EditPlaceForm.swift

Updated:

```
//
//  EditPlaceForm.swift
//

import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation

struct EditPlaceForm: View {
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    var place: Place
    
    @State private var name = ""
    @State private var street = ""
    @State private var city = ""
    @State private var state = ""
    @State private var zip = ""
    @State private var country = ""
    
    @State private var showAlert = false
    @State private var alertText = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section (header: Text("Name")) {
                    TextField("Name", text: $name)
                }
                Section (header: Text("Address")) {
                    VStack {
                        TextField("Street", text: $street)
                        TextField("City", text: $city)
                        HStack {
                            TextField("State", text: $state)
                            Divider()
                            TextField("ZIP", text: $zip)
                        }
                        TextField("Country", text: $country)
                    }
                }
                Section(header: Text("Save")) {
                    Button (action: {
                        save()
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Save")
                    })
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Edit Place")
            .alert(isPresented: $showAlert, content: {
                Alert(title: Text("Error"), message: Text(alertText))
            })
        }
        .onAppear {
            loadPlaceData()
        }
    }
    
    func loadPlaceData() {
        name = place.name
        street = place.street
        city = place.city
        state = place.state
        zip = place.zip
        country = place.country
    }
    
    func save() {
        let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
        geocoder.geocodeAddressString("\(street), \(city) \(state), \(zip), \(country)", completionHandler: {
            placemarks, error in
            
            if error != nil {
                print("Error forward geocoding")
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
                alertText = "Encountered geocoding error."
                showAlert = true
                return
            }
            
            if placemarks == nil {
                print("No placemarks found")
                alertText = "Location could not be found."
                showAlert = true
                return
            }
            
            let placemark = placemarks![0]
            
            let testVars = [
                placemark.thoroughfare,
                placemark.locality,
                placemark.administrativeArea,
                placemark.country,
                placemark.postalCode
            ]
            for testVar in testVars {
                if testVar == nil {
                    print("Not enough information to complete place")
                    alertText = "Not enough information."
                    showAlert = true
                    return
                }
            }
            
            if placemark.location == nil {
                print("Not enough information to complete place")
                alertText = "Not enough information."
                showAlert = true
                return
            }
            
            viewContext.performAndWait {
                place.street = placemark.subThoroughfare! + " " + placemark.thoroughfare!
                place.city = placemark.locality!
                place.state = placemark.administrativeArea!
                place.country = placemark.country!
                place.zip = placemark.postalCode!
                place.latitude = placemark.location!.coordinate.latitude
                place.longitude = placemark.location!.coordinate.latitude
                do {
                    try viewContext.save()
                    presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                } catch {
                    print("ERROR: FAILED TO SAVE PLACE DETAILS")
                    alertText = "Failed to save."
                    showAlert = true
                }
            }
        })
    }
}

struct EditPlaceForm_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    
    private static var viewContext = PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext
    
    static var previews: some View {
        EditPlaceForm(place: Place.getDefault(context: viewContext))
    }
}
```

## Original Post

### Setup

My app has a main page which is a navigation view. On that page, there are navigation links. One of those links leads to the "Places" page which contains a list. The list items on that page are navigation links to detail pages for CoreData entities called Place. In the detail pages I have an edit button that opens an editing form as a sheet.

### Intended Behavior

You open the details view from the "Places" view, using the navigation link. You then click the edit button and change some of the information. When you click save, the editing form closes and the changes are reflected in the details view. You can then click the back button to go back to the "Places" view.

### Current Behavior

You open the details view from the "Places" view, using the navigation link. You then click the edit button and change some of the information. When you save, the editing form closes and the changes are reflected in the details view, but the back button has disappeared and you are stuck in the details view.

Video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lzj-hOCb7hgMutQQwPl0ShR7l-c9sDib/view?usp=sharing

### Code

"Places" view:

```
//
//  PlacesList.swift
//

import SwiftUI

struct PlacesList: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    @FetchRequest(entity: Place.entity(), sortDescriptors: [
        NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
    ])
    private var places: FetchedResults<Place>
    
    @State private var showAddPlaceForm = false
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach (places) { place in
                NavigationLink (destination: PlaceDetail(place: place)) {
                    PlaceRow(place: place)
                }
            }
            .onDelete(perform: deleteRow)
        }
        .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
        .navigationTitle(Text("Places"))
        .navigationBarItems(trailing:
            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    showAddPlaceForm = true
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                        .imageScale(.large)
                })
                .sheet(isPresented: $showAddPlaceForm) {
                    NewPlaceForm()
                }
            }
        )
    }
    
    func deleteRow(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        for offset in offsets {
            viewContext.performAndWait {
                viewContext.delete(places[offset])
                try? viewContext.save()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct PlacesList_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    
    private static var viewContext = PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext
    
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationView {
            PlacesList()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext)
        }
    }
}
```

PlaceRow.swift

```
//
//  PlaceRow.swift
//

import SwiftUI

struct PlaceRow: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    @ObservedObject var place: Place
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack (alignment: .leading) {
            Text(place.name)
                .font(.headline)
            Group {
                Text(place.street)
                Text(place.city) + Text(", ") + Text(place.state)
            }
            .font(.subheadline)
            .foregroundColor(.secondary)
        }
    }
}

struct PlaceRow_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    
    private static var viewContext = PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext
    
    static var previews: some View {
        List {
            PlaceRow(place: Place.getDefault(context: viewContext))
        }
    }
}
```

PlaceDetail.swift

```
//
//  PlaceDetail.swift
//

import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation

struct PlaceDetail: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    @ObservedObject var place: Place
    
    @State private var showEditForm = false
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Address")
                    .font(.headline)
                Group {
                    Text(place.street)
                    Text(place.cityStateZIPString)
                    Text(place.country)
                }
                .font(.subheadline)
                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
            }
            VStack {
                MapView(place: place)
                    .frame(height: 300)
            }
            if place.encodedAddress != nil {
                Link(destination:
                    URL(string: "http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=\(place.encodedAddress!)")!,
                    label: {
                        HStack {
                            Text("Get Directions with Apple Maps")
                            Spacer()
                            Image(systemName: "chevron.forward.circle")
                                .imageScale(.large)
                        }
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    })
                Link(destination:
                        URL(string: "https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&destination=\(place.encodedAddress!)")!,
                     label: {
                        HStack {
                            Text("Get Directions with Google Maps")
                            Spacer()
                            Image(systemName: "chevron.forward.circle")
                                .imageScale(.large)
                        }
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                     })
            }
            
        }
        .toolbar {
            Button(action: {
                showEditForm = true
            }, label: {
                Image(systemName: "pencil.circle")
            })
        }
        .navigationTitle(place.name)
        .sheet(isPresented: $showEditForm, content: {
            EditPlaceForm(place: place)
        })
    }
}

struct PlaceDetail_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    
    static var viewContext = PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext
    
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationView {
            PlaceDetail(place: Place.getDefault(context: viewContext))
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, viewContext)
        }
    }
}
```

EditPlaceForm.swift

```
//
//  EditPlaceForm.swift
//

import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation

struct EditPlaceForm: View {
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    @ObservedObject var place: Place
    @State private var showAlert = false
    @State private var alertText = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section (header: Text("Name")) {
                    TextField("Name", text: $place.name)
                }
                Section (header: Text("Address")) {
                    VStack {
                        TextField("Street", text: $place.street)
                        TextField("City", text: $place.city)
                        HStack {
                            TextField("State", text: $place.state)
                            TextField("ZIP", text: $place.zip)
                        }
                        TextField("Country", text: $place.country)
                    }
                }
                Section(header: Text("Save")) {
                    Button (action: {
                        save()
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Save")
                    })
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Edit Place")
            .alert(isPresented: $showAlert, content: {
                Alert(title: Text("Error"), message: Text(alertText))
            })
        }
    }
    
    func save() {
        let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
        geocoder.geocodeAddressString(place.address, completionHandler: {
            placemarks, error in
            
            if error != nil {
                print("Error forward geocoding")
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
                alertText = "Encountered geocoding error."
                showAlert = true
                return
            }
            
            if placemarks == nil {
                print("No placemarks found")
                alertText = "Location could not be found."
                showAlert = true
                return
            }
            
            let placemark = placemarks![0]
            
            let testVars = [
                placemark.thoroughfare,
                placemark.locality,
                placemark.administrativeArea,
                placemark.country,
                placemark.postalCode
            ]
            for testVar in testVars {
                if testVar == nil {
                    print("Not enough information to complete place")
                    alertText = "Not enough information."
                    showAlert = true
                    return
                }
            }
            
            if placemark.location == nil {
                print("Not enough information to complete place")
                alertText = "Not enough information."
                showAlert = true
                return
            }
            
            viewContext.performAndWait {
                place.street = placemark.subThoroughfare! + " " + placemark.thoroughfare!
                place.city = placemark.locality!
                place.state = placemark.administrativeArea!
                place.country = placemark.country!
                place.zip = placemark.postalCode!
                place.latitude = placemark.location!.coordinate.latitude
                place.longitude = placemark.location!.coordinate.latitude
                do {
                    try viewContext.save()
                    presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                } catch {
                    print("ERROR: FAILED TO SAVE PLACE DETAILS")
                }
            }
        })
    }
}

struct EditPlaceForm_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    
    private static var viewContext = PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext
    
    static var previews: some View {
        EditPlaceForm(place: Place.getDefault(context: viewContext))
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to refresh all those views marked with  `@ObservedObject ` on project view change? Try removing  `ObservedObject ` in PlaceDetail.swift and keep  `var place: Place ` and check output once.In short only mark observedObject on views you want to refresh.

Comment: @TusharSharma Yes, I want PlaceRow, and PlaceDetail to update. I suppose it's not necessary for EditPlaceForm to update, but removing `@ObservedObject` makes it so that place is no longer a binding. Adding `@State` to fix it makes it so that the form can't be modified.

Comment: Having `@ObservedObject` is the correct way of observing the `ObservableObject` the disappearing back button is the bug/issue. I would report/focus on that, try replacing `presentationMode` with the "new" `dismiss` or present and dismiss with a dedicated `Bool` variable. There is way to much code here you should provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if you want more specific help. You can use the basic `Item` that is provided in a template project and recreate the least amount of code needed.